# add a row in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I want to show to the user in the datagridview the source of the articles informations ( famille1 or famille2) :

my code :

```
Dim dt1 As DataTable = New db_con().selectdata( _
              "SELECT famille1.ID, famille1.Article, famille1.quantité, famille1.prixch, famille1.prixvn, famille1.dateex FROM famille1;")
        Dim dt2 As DataTable = New db_con().selectdata( _
              "SELECT famille2.ID, famille2.Article, famille2.quantité, famille2.prixch, famille2.prixvn, famille2.dateex FROM famille2;")

        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt1.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt1.Rows(i)(0), dt1.Rows(i)(1), dt1.Rows(i)(2), dt1.Rows(i)(3), dt1.Rows(i)(4), dt1.Rows(i)(5))
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt2.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt2.Rows(i)(0), dt2.Rows(i)(1), dt2.Rows(i)(2), dt2.Rows(i)(3), dt2.Rows(i)(4), dt2.Rows(i)(5))
        Next
```

i think the code should be like this :

```
Dim dt1 As DataTable = New db_con().selectdata( _
              "SELECT famille1.ID, famille1.Article, famille1.quantité, famille1.prixch, famille1.prixvn, famille1.dateex FROM famille1;")
        Dim dt2 As DataTable = New db_con().selectdata( _
              "SELECT famille2.ID, famille2.Article, famille2.quantité, famille2.prixch, famille2.prixvn, famille2.dateex FROM famille2;")

        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt1.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt1.Rows("famille1"), dt1.Rows(i)(0), dt1.Rows(i)(1), dt1.Rows(i)(2), dt1.Rows(i)(3), dt1.Rows(i)(4), dt1.Rows(i)(5))
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt2.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt1.Rows("famille2"), dt2.Rows(i)(0), dt2.Rows(i)(1), dt2.Rows(i)(2), dt2.Rows(i)(3), dt2.Rows(i)(4), dt2.Rows(i)(5))
        Next
```

So, i want to show in a Row in the Datagridview the source of the data (famille1 or famille2)

hope that is clear :/

Comment: The NET DB provider objects will do all of that for you.  use the DataTable as the DataSource for the DGV.  When the user types in the new row provided a new row is added for you.  DataBinding is a wonderful thing.  Please read [ask] and take the [Tour]

Answer (score 0):

Run this query instead:

```
SELECT famille1.ID, famille1.Article, famille1.quantité, famille1.prixch, famille1.prixvn, famille1.dateex FROM famille1
UNION ALL
SELECT famille2.ID, famille2.Article, famille2.quantité, famille2.prixch, famille2.prixvn, famille2.dateex FROM famille2
```

The resulting DataTable, just do:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS.

```
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()

    SQL = "famille1.ID, famille1.Article, famille1.quantité,famille1.prixch, famille1.prixvn, famille1.dateex FROM famille1"

    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; user id=root; database=DATABASENAME"

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()

        ContactsCommand.Connection = MysqlConn
        ContactsCommand.CommandText = SQL

        ContactsAdapter.SelectCommand = ContactsCommand

        ContactsAdapter.Fill(ContactsData)

        DATAGRIDVIEW1.DataSource = ContactsData

    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & myerror.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```